# Associations in java class vs. associations in mysql db

Tags: java, uml, relationship

I have the following relationship:

```
===========        =====================          ============
| building|-1----M-| building_occupant |-M------1-| occupant |
===========        =====================          ============
```

I'm supposed to write a Association class in java. I'm new to this language so I'm not sure whether there already exists some built-in data structure or functionality that fits this design (without using a database.. has to be a class).
Is there a way to store the data in such as way that I can retrieve multiple rows with one request? ..E.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM house_occupant Where occupant_id = 1;
```

Basically, I need help finding the best implementation design for this relationship using classes.

NOTE: No persistence required.

Comment: Have a look at JPA (Java Persistence API) which should provide what you're after.

Comment: no persistence required.. This is for a hw assignment. I do not need any code.. just a recommendation as to what data structures to use or if I should create my own. E.g.: I thought about a hashmap of <building, occupant> ... but in that case, while I can get all occupants for a building, I cannot get all buildings for an occupant

Comment: Is it required no to use persistence or is persistence just optional? Besides that, have a look at how JPA entities are implemented (simple references, collections being used etc.) to get an idea of the data structures needed (you can skip the mapping parts if you don't need persistence).

Comment: ok.. will do. Persistence is optional. thanks